# Drupal Ubercart Merchant ID and Key are incorrect?

Tags: drupal, soap, ubercart

When I checkout in Ubercart the merchant key and merchant id are incorrect. In my configuration they are correct, but when the login credentials are displayed during checkout, they are jumbled.

I am using the uc_domain module to manage different payment gateways per domain. My original domain is working correctly, but my new domain, as seen in the image, is not working correctly.

[image: Ubercart error]

Any idea what I'm missing here?